# Pandas: How to Unstack Every Third Index(row) and widen the DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following sample DataFrame (wherein the real data set, the pattern repeats for many rows). I wish to move the
'Category' 'Section' 'Level' 'Result' from rows to column labels.

The row following are the features of the above, and are

Input Code is representative of the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Joe Bloggs', 'Category',
...                                   'A', 'Jane Doe', 'Category',
...                                   'B'],
...                    'Date': ['2020-06-19' , 'Section', '1', '2020-06-19',
...                            'Section', '2'],
...                    'Time': ["09:00:00", "Level", "First", "16:30:06",
...                                 "Level", "Third"],
...                   'type': ["Login", "Result",
...                          "Pass", "Logout",
...                          "Result", "Fail"]})
```

Desired Output is as follows:

[image: Desired Output is]

Many thanks

Comment: can you test `df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[2::3].values,columns=df.iloc[1]\
                     .values,index=df.iloc[2::3].index),how='outer').dropna()` ?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```py
df=pd.concat([\
    df.iloc[0::3].reset_index(drop=True), \
    pd.DataFrame(\
        df.iloc[2::3].to_numpy(), \
        columns=df.iloc[1].to_numpy()\
    )], axis=1\
)
```

Outputs:

```py
         name        Date      Time  ... Section  Level Result
0  Joe Bloggs  2020-06-19  09:00:00  ...       1  First   Pass
1    Jane Doe  2020-06-19  16:30:06  ...       2  Third   Fail
```

Comment: Thanks, does exactly as described. However, I have just realised that the input data set I have doesn't repeat in the sequence I thought it did! Back to the drawing board, but this really helps me. Thank you.

Comment: quite similair to my solution, I was thinking of using str.contains to find each header row and the one after to slice it but list slicing is probably the easiest/safest